# Find all possible value of c

Tags: vieta-jumping

> Let a and b be non-negative integers. If $\frac{a^2+ab+b^2}{ab-2} = c$ for some non-negative integer c, find all possible values of c.

Can somebody give me some hint or tips on how to solve this? I have tried to use a computer to brute-force and found that c must be 0, 6, 13. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Proof is needed that there is no other value of c other than 0, 6, 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fair amount of detail if all written out. However, what it comes down to is that, using Vieta Jumping, in the first quadrant, if there are any integer solutions to
$$ x^2 - Bxy + y^2 = -2(B+1),  $$
then there must be integer solutions, Hurwitz's Fundamental Solutions, in the bounded arc with between the point of minimum $y$ and the point of minimum $x,$ meaning in
$$ x \geq \frac{2y}{B}  $$ and
$$ y \geq \frac{2x}{B}  $$
In the picture, we see integer points $(3,1)$ and $(1,3)$ between the slanted lines.

[image]
However, when $B > 12,$ and we ask about the smaller value of $x,$ we find that it is
$$  \frac{4B+6}{B + \sqrt{B^2 - 8B -12}}  $$ and
$$ 2 < \frac{4B+6}{B + \sqrt{B^2 - 8B -12}} < 3  $$ 
[image]
In turn, this means that there are no integer points on the arc between the slanted lines, and no integer points at all, when $B > 12.$

Vieta Jumping is just a means to an end. The important stuff is the collection of inequalities that need to be investigated. The best description is [Hurwitz 1907](http://ki.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hurwitz_A_1907.pdf)

Comment: Thanks! I read another post on the same question except the '2' in the denominator is replaced by a '1'

Comment: I didn't find it before because google didn't recognize \frac as a division sign '/'

Comment: @KGSHbteamMineTeamBeastO_ if you click on the Vieta Jumping tag under the question you should be able to find anything recent. I think there are under 50 items, I will check